# Cleaning OSM graph retrieved with NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx, openstreetmap

I am using the OSM road network to conduct shortest path calculations using OSMx and NetworkX. I am having a problem because I am working with large regions.

I am using graph from bbox to retrieve the drive network in a region. I am considering `retain_all=True` in order to maintain all the isolated networks due to the analysis is around isolated areas in a country.

**Could I delete isolated networks from a graph considering the number of edges?** For example, I would like to delete only the isolated networks in my graph with less than 10 edges, is that possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible, if you provide an example, we could help you with an implementation…

Comment: You could loop over the 'components' (connected subgraphs) with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html). Then count the edges in them.